# Averages for multiple lines of text file, Python 3

Tags: python, tuples

I have a .txt file with lines of grades that I need to calculate the averages for. I've really hit a wall with figuring out how to get the averaging function to iterate every line of the text file. For some reason I get a syntax error if there is an odd amount of lines. And when the line amount is even python returns every **other** line. Heres my code.

```
with open('grades.txt','r') as source:
def toNumbers():
    global t
    g = source.readline()
    t = eval(g)
def sumList(variable):
    a = sum(variable)/len(variable)
    print('average:', round(a))
for lines in source:
    toNumbers()
    sumList(t)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify your `tonumbers()` function to be:

```
def toNumbers(line):
    res = eval(line)
    return res
```

And your main for loop to be:

```
for line in source.read():
    t = toNumbers(line)
    sumList(t)
```

In general using `global` is discouraged, you should try to get around using it by using arguments and returning results. Hope I helped!